# Parallel test processes within docker container

Tags: parallel-processing, docker, docker-compose, parallel-testing

I'm executing `parallel_tests` within a docker container, e.g. one host command.

[parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/blob/master/lib/parallel_tests/cli.rb) will examine the resources, and spawn a process per core, and in my instance I have 8 cores available:

```
# docker info
Containers: 5
Images: 75
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 85
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-49-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.61 GiB
Name: camacho
ID: ZOYN:QGDO:UGMJ:TDDM:WEEM:ZEHJ:4OKB:V5WR:RGCL:NOKG:F5W5:SDEL
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

On the same machine without docker, it is clear that these tests are running in parallel and use up all the available resources (exactly what we want for CI).

When executed within docker, it seems that everything runs in a single process, and results only come synchronously from each of the test runners (and it is much slower by comparison).

Do I need to run parallel host commands for it to use resources?  Can I set an option to allow my docker command to fork more parallel processes?

Comment: It's also possible that parallel processes are running fine and I'm bottlenecking elsewhere...any comments/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: My original question still stands, but after some digging note that I [have found that my ubuntu host isn't performing as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617243/docker-compose-performance-on-ubuntu-host)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem was running on OSX with virtualbox, and virtualbox was setup to run with only one core. `dinghy halt` then `virtualbox` | `settings` | `system` | `processor`.  Set it to the number of threads i.e. 8 threads for a quad core hyperthreaded cpu.