# Docker performance on ubuntu host 2x+ worse than OSX host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Ok, let's start over after a bunch of investigation.  Here is what we know:

#### Ubuntu host

15.04 on i7 3820 (quad 3.6) and Samsung 850 pro SSD 512gb SATA 6

```
$ docker info
Containers: 2
Images: 101
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.19.0-28-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 15.04
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.61 GiB
Name: camacho
ID: ZOYN:QGDO:UGMJ:TDDM:WEEM:ZEHJ:4OKB:V5WR:RGCL:NOKG:F5W5:SDEL
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

#### OSX host

10.10.5 on i7 (quad 2.7) and Apple SSD 512gb SD512E SATA 6 (2+ years old)

```
$ docker info
Containers: 3
Images: 185
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 191
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.0.9-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.8.1 (TCL 6.3); master : 7f12e95 - Thu Aug 13 03:24:56 UTC 2015
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 3.858 GiB
Name: dinghy
ID: PNNP:PI3E:CRUK:27RI:IPHW:HROF:NQA2:XKV6:VGCZ:WT7B:BZ7R:USWD
Debug mode (server): true
File Descriptors: 21
Goroutines: 54
System Time: 2015-09-24T19:16:01.715069994Z
EventsListeners: 1
Init SHA1: 
Init Path: /usr/local/bin/docker
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

#### Observations

1. dockerized rspec running 2x+ faster on OSX
2. sysbench io results are terrible on Ubuntu
3. dockerized iozone results are as expected (ubuntu slightly faster)
4. hardware check complete, ubuntu host is on a SATA 6 cable and port

#### iozone results

```
docker run -it threadx/docker-ubuntu-iozone
$ iozone -R -l 5 -u 5 -r 4k -s 100m -F /home/f1 /home/f2 /home/f3 /home/f4 /home/f5 | tee -a /tmp/iozone_results.txt &
```

[image: iozone-bench]

## Summary

I'm dockerizing our test process because we need stability and concurrency.  We've done a bunch of work to limit test times, and a 2x increase in times is a terrible step backwards.

Sysbench shows the ubuntu host performing 4x worse than OSX, and I have no understanding of that.  `dd` and `iozone` tests show the ubuntu host to be performing as expected.

## Question

Why is my rspec performance worse on the ubuntu host which has faster resources? Where should I investigate? Is sysbench io test an indicator or an anomaly?  What are sources of bad performance in dockerized ubuntu?

Comment: It seems like there is a problem attaching to the web container, I see: `Creating 2_db_1...
Creating 2_web_1...
Creating 2_elasticsearch_1...
Attaching to ` then nothing.  Running a `ps` after a bit shows the web container has exited.  Currently the web container is configured to run mysql sysbench, and I'm expecting output on stdout.

Comment: I'm running another io sysbench after the [ufw change](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#enable-ufw-forwarding)

Comment: no change with ufw, investigating storage drivers, current kernel is `3.16.0-49-generic`

Comment: Upgrading to [15.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes)

Comment: After upgrade to 15.04 `Total transferred 3.215Gb  (10.974Mb/sec)`.  Next trying overlay.

Comment: overlay made no difference.  sysbench looks terrible, dd and iozone look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is PCIe vs SATA 6 interfaces.  The latest generation of Macbook Pro PCIe is even faster.